# Stored procedure gives error: query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure as shown below. I always though that the last select's result would be returned automatically, but I am getting this error, and I don't know why, can anyone enlighten me?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pGetPlans() RETURNS TABLE (
    title varchar(16),
    full_cost money,
    subtitle varchar(128),
    blurb varchar(128),
    details varchar(128)[],
    final_str text)
AS $$
DECLARE
full_cost      tplan.cost%TYPE;
current_cost   tplan.cost%TYPE;
amount_saved   tplan.cost%TYPE;
percent_saved  float;
monthly_cost   tplan.cost%TYPE;
one_month_cost tplan.cost%TYPE;
you_save       tplan.cost%TYPE;

BEGIN
    select
        cost
    into
        one_month_cost
    from
        tplan
    where
        is_base = true;

    select
        p.title,
        p.cost,
        p.subtitle,
        p.blurb,
        p.details,
        '1 Month Cost is: ' || one_month_cost::text as final_str
    from
        tplan p
    where
        p.status = 'A';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thank you
Crouz

Comment: this is because you write SELECT query but not return anything from that.

Comment: But I read in the documents that if the last statement is a select, then it gets returned automatically. So how do I return the result set then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I always though that the last select's result would be returned
>   automatically

This is only true for function written in the `sql` language , as opposed to `plpgsql` and others.

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) quote:

> SQL functions execute an arbitrary list of SQL statements, returning
>   the result of the last query in the list.

Use `RETURN QUERY SELECT...` as the last instruction to achieve the same in `plpgsql`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, such a simple mistake on my part (still learning I must admit). Regards, Crouz